# Run select change event by clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below code works, but I need to fire `sela on change` event by clicking on `button`, so console is written `ipsum`.

Something like this:

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('.sela').change('ipsum');  // console...
});
```

Is it possible?

```js
$('.sela').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'ipsum'){console.log('ipsum');}
});

$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('.sela').val('ipsum');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='sela'>
<option>lorem</option>
<option>ipsum</option>
</select>

<button>CLICK</button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$('.sela').val('ipsum').change();` you need to trigger the change event after change the value.

```js
$('.sela').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'ipsum'){console.log('ipsum');}
});

$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('.sela').val('ipsum').change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='sela'>
<option>lorem</option>
<option>ipsum</option>
</select>

<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: you're totally welcome @qadenza .. Have a nice day :-)

Answer (score 1):

Change event is fired when the value is changed by users interaction on page and not when value is modified using code.

Here you need to use `.change()` or `.trigger("change")` after changing the value:

```js
$('.sela').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'ipsum'){console.log('ipsum');}
});

$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('.sela').val('ipsum').change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='sela'>
<option>lorem</option>
<option>ipsum</option>
</select>

<button>CLICK</button>
```